# how do I read in numbers from a file and assign variables to them when the numbers have some text before them on the line in the file

Tags: python, readline, read-data

I am reading in data from a text file in python. one of the lines that is being read is the following

Grid-ref=   4, 323

I want to be able to assign the 4 and 323 to variables xref and yref respectively. This line appears several times throughout the file with different numbers so i want to change xref and yref each time this line appears. The text 'Grid-ref=   ' appears each time.
How do I ignore the first part and be able to access the values to store them in variables? Either the first part can be ignored, or i can do an if statement for 'if the line starts with Grid-ref'. Either would be fine but i dont know how to do either of them.

I know which line numbers the Gridref would appear in, it is lines 11x - 6, where x is an integer starting from 1, and incrementing by 1 to a large number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you got each line separated:

```
line = ‘Grid-ref= 4, 323’
x,y = line[9:].replace(" ", "").split(',')
```